# Jupyter and Haskell - packages

Tags: haskell, jupyter-notebook

I am working in Linux Ubuntu 16.04, my question is when I open in Jupyter new Haskell notebook, I want to import i.e. Text.CSV package that was previously installed through terminal with cabal, but I get an error that Jupyter can not find a module named... So my question is, do I have to / or how can I install packages through Jupyter, or must I sync Haskell under Jupyter somehow with 'original' Haskell programm?

I am new to Haskell and Jupyter notebook. Thank you very much.

Comment: How did you install IHaskell?

Comment: This very question is discussed on the IHaskell home page https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/blob/master/README.md#where-are-my-packages-ihaskell--stack

Answer (score 1):

The textbook solution is noted above, on the iHaskell github page.

However, a "quick and dirty" solution is to just install the module while in the notebook using GHCi-style shell commands, as detailed here: https://github.com/jamesdbrock/ihaskell-notebook#stack-global-project

In this case, to install Text.CSV, you would simply run
`:!stack install csv`

Note that when you use this quick & dirty method, you will have to restart your iHaskell kernel. You only have to install it once, it will be available the next time you wish to load/import the module (no need to install it twice).